# Error while migrate wordpress to drupal

Tags: migrations

I want to migrate a wordpress blog to drupal. I create an "Article blog" content type with three fields: body, tags and categories (plus default title field). I am trying to import with [Wordpress migrate](https://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) (version 7.x-2.2) via url or file, both solution return same error while importing for each article:

> Illegal string offset 'translatable' File drupal_root/modules/field/field.multilingual.inc, line 176

I am using drupal 7.22 with commons profile 7.x-3.2.
All other imports (tag, categories and attachments) works fine.

Do you have an idea about how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can export the content to a csv format. Then use [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import the csv file to the mapped fields.

Comment: doesn't work... I have a to old wordpress version... and can't do anything for that at this point. Not a problem, I have another solution... thanks for your help